# PHP Body of email showing in Gmail but not in Office 365

Tags: php, email, outlook, gmail

I have an SMTP server set up on my local machine.

In my PHP script I am saving .txt files to a directory that the SMTP server is listening to. When the script saves to the file the SMTP server sends it off.

My script looks like this:

```
$content  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$content .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" . PHP_EOL;
$content .= 'From: user@domain.com' ."\r\n";
$content .= 'To: user@domain.com' . "\r\n";
$content .= "CC: susan@example.com\r\n";
$content .= 'Subject: Email test' . "\r\n";

$content .= 'Service Required - '. $_POST['service'] . "\r\n";
$content .= 'Contact - ' . $_POST['contact'] . "\r\n";
$content .= 'About - ' . $_POST['about'] . "\r\n";
$content .= 'Files - File size was to big for upload';

$fp = fopen('C:/inetpub/mailroot/pickup/email.txt',"wb");
fwrite($fp,$content);
fclose($fp);
```

When sending to Gmail the body appears.

but when sent to outlook the body is empty.

Comment: Also, depending on the software watching reading those text files, watch out for your mail server getting hijacked. A malicious post could presumably construct some text output that could then run riot. I would escape your POST variables before writing to file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
$content .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" . PHP_EOL;
```

with:

```
$content .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1" . PHP_EOL;
```

Not 100% sure, but Outlook could be not showing anything because you're telling it to expect HTML, but it's not receiving any. If this is the (only) problem then you've just been lucky that Google tries to second guess for you!

Also:

```
$content .= 'Subject: Email test' . "\r\n";
```

With:

```
//double new line between headers and content
$content .= 'Subject: Email test' . "\r\n\r\n";
```

SMTP expects there to be a double new line between headers and content. Again, I think Google have done a good job guessing what's going on there!

Comment: Thanks for the advice button but unfortunately did not work. still saying no preview available. 

 ill make sure to escape them. only set it up this way because the mail() function does not seem to want to work on IIS :( IV set up the SMTP to only accept from localhost.

Comment: Thanks so much! your awesome. adding the double new line worked!.
how do i accept this as the awnser on here?

Comment: Cool no problem. Provided an extra explanation. I'm not sure how to accept but I think you did it!